# Tener librerias node offline

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Tengo una duda. ¿Existe alguna manera de tener todos los paquetes de librerias de node de forma offline?. Mi situacion es la de que quiero hacer programacion js con node con un portatil sin conexion a internet y si necesito instalar por ejemplo express o uuid ncesito estar online. ¿Existe algun pack de librerias donde las descargue para tenerlas disponibles offline? Gracias

Comment: ¿Y porque me votan negativo?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones o recomendaciones terminan cerradas

Comment: Su pregunta no es opinion o recomendación. Es una pregunta muy válida de iniciante y otros podrán beneficiarse de este intercâmbio.

Comment: @ildefonsoarevalo si la respuesta fue lo que buscabas no olvides marcarla como respuesta  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe un "pack" a como lo haz descrito. Sin embargo puedes hacerlo tu mismo, simplemente descargarlos la primera vez de manera "normal" y luego desconectarte de internet. `npm` (o `yarn`) lo que hace es mirar a tu archivo `package.json` y por cada dependencia/paquete que va encontrando checa en la carpeta `node_modules` a ver si ya está ahí y si no está entonces descarga el paquete (prefiero la palabra dependencia).

Al final todas las dependencias habrán sido descargadas y listo. Siempre y cuando no agregues nuevas dependencias (o modifiques los archivos `package.json` y `lock` si los tienes), deberías poder continuar usar los comandos de `npm` o `yarn` sin internet.

Con eso en mente, tu podrías "armar" tu propio "pack" haciendo un `package.json` con todas las dependencias que te interesan, correr `npm install` y al finalizar, hacer una copia de tu carpeta `node_modules`. Esta la puedes copiar y compartir con tu equipo y será exactamente lo mismo.